# Ignore file or folder through Jgit in Java

Tags: java, git, github, gitlab, jgit

I am using JGit to execute Git command in Java (1.8). I am able to use different command such as

```
git init
git pull
git add
git commit
git push
```

on a repository directory. This directory contains certain file(s) or folder(s), that I want to ignore while adding/committing in to git repository. 
How I can achieve this using this JGit library in Java.

Thanks

Comment: Use `.gitignore` files to prevent files from being added (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). JGit's `AddCommand` understands them just as native Git.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann thanks for your suggestion. I was thinking about this approach. However, I found FastIgnoreRule class, that is related to ignoring file/folders. But I don't know how to use this.

Comment: You could for example have a look in the repository of the library https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/tree/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test there are some tests using `FastIgnoreRule`.

Comment: If you are using the `AddCommand` you don't need to case about `FastIgnoreRule`, it's used by the command internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank U Rudiger Herrmann.
As Rudiger Herrmann commented, there is no out of box features or method(s) in the API, provides to ignore file(s) or folder(s). We need to create a file .gitignore and put all that required to be ignored in to the .gitignore file. The add() method recognizes this file while adding file(s) in to repository.

```
So, in order to ignore file(s) or folder(s) :
1. create a .gitignore file.
2. add all required  file(s) and folder(s), needs to be ignored.
3. finally call add() method of API.
```

Sample .gitignore file content:

```
### Java ###
# Compiled class file
.class
*.log
# folders to be ignored
**/logs
**/classpath
git-ignore.txt
folder_name/
```